# Dropdown menu still receiving duplicates from dataset

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with data from a firestore db but I can't seem to get out the duplicate entries... i tried it with an "in" statement as well a includes() function but they do not remove and they get pushed into the new array. Any help is much appreciated !

```
useEffect(() => {
        const q = query(collection(db, "Location"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            const locations = [];
            const auxLocations = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if(doc.data().place != '' && (!(doc.data() in locations))){
                    locations.push(doc.data());
                }
                
            });
            
            setLocations(locations);
           
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [])
```

[image]

Comment: `if(doc.data().place != ''` ---> here, the code checks for `doc.data().place`. Specifically, it checks for `.place`. And yet, here: `!(doc.data() in locations` the code looks whether `doc.data()` is present/absent in `locations`. So, which is it - `doc.data()` **OR** `doc.data().place`?

Comment: Yes it should look for doc.data().place which should not be empty and not already exist in the array Locations. I''ve tried adding .place in te "in" statement but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried changing: `locations.push(doc.data());` to `locations.push(doc.data().place);` as well?

Comment: Hi , yes also tried that unfortunatly ....

Comment: Okay, please update the question with `doc.data().place` code as well as please provide the data received on `querySnapshot` variable in order to simulate the issue. If `querySnapshot` is an array of objects where each object has a method named `data()` and each call to this method returns an object which has the prop `place` and the value corresponding to this prop is of type `string`, then: `setLocations([...new Set(querySnapshot.map(d => d.data().place))]);` will remove duplicates and store only unique `place`s to state-variable `locations`.